# Convert Calls to undefined function in javascript

Tags: javascript

First of all, I am just starting in JS and it is some sort of black magic to me so pardon me if my question is not relevant.

I have some object. I would like to convert calls to undefined functions into another function . For example, if funcUndef are undefined functions, I would like:

```
obj.funcUndef(param1, param2, param3, etc)
```

to be converted into:

```
obj.execute("funcUndef", "param1, param2, param3, etc");
```

Is it possible to intercept calls to undefined and execute my own function (which will be in charge of making the conversion and calling execute function)?

Comment: i'm sorry but javascript does not have that facility.

Comment: This won't really be possible until [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) land, unless you want to call all functions through an intermediary function.